# Monitoring GHC activity

Tags: haskell, ghc

If GHC takes a long time to compile something, is there a way to find out what it's doing?

Firstly, it would be nice to know if I've actually crashed the compiler (i.e., put it into some sort of infinite loop somehow), or whether it's actually making progress, but just very slowly.

Secondly, it would be nice to know exactly what part of the compilation process GHC is having trouble with. Is it the parsing, or desugaring, or type-checking, or Core optimisation, or code generation, or...?

Is there some way to monitor what's going on? (Bearing in mind that if GHC is taking a long time, that probably means it's doing a lot of work, so if you ask for too much output it's going to be *huge!*)

GHC already tells you which modules it's trying to (re)compile. In my case, the problem is a single self-contained module. I'd like to know where GHC is getting stuck.

Comment: You could build a profiled version of GHC and then use the standard profiling tools to see what it is up to after the fact.

Comment: You can ask it to be chatty by specifying a verbosity `-v4` tells you a **lot** of what's going on - yes, the output will be huge, but if you just want to monitor it, let it go to the terminal, that remembers only the last 1000 or so lines, usually.

Comment: In my experience, GHC going into an infinite loop can be recognized because anything productive it would be doing that slowly generally makes it eat lots of memory as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Daniel Fischer's comment, I tried running GHC with different verbosity options.

- `-v1`: Produced a bit more output, but nothing during the main compilation step.
- `-v2`: Tells you what step GHC is currently doing (parser, desugar, type check, simplifier, etc). This is pretty much what I actually wanted.
- `-v3`: Appears to make the simplifier actually dump what it's doing to the console - bad idea while compiling 8MB of source code!

So it seems that `-v2` is the place to start.

(In the specific case of the program that prompted this question, it seems GHC is spending forever in the type checking phase.)

Comment: If it's type checking, it could be stuck in an infinite loop resolving undecidable instances. Type inference could also be an issue, since H-M inference has a *horrible* worst-case time complexity. Those are the only reasonable causes I can think of. Did you ever resolve the issue?

Comment: @C.A.McCann I was merely trying to compile a _huge_ source file. It doesn't contain anything particularly unusual, it's just very, very big. I "solved" the problem by making it much smaller.